# My query returns 0 results when it should return 1

Tags: php, mysql

The whole query skips my first if statement to else - "NE VRNE NIČ"... Here's my
LINK TO DATABASE STRUCTURE: http://ibin.co/1j1bFYAswzXI

PS: $slug is the same as $naslov, but it get's modified throught the function.

```
    $id = "SELECT id FROM novica
           where slug = '$slug'";

    $result = $conn->query($id);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
        $idat = $row["id"];
        }
    }
    else //IT SKIPS DIRECTLY TO THE ELSE - SO IT HAS TO BE WITH QUERY $id
    {
        echo "NE VRNE NIČ!";
    }




    $sql = "UPDATE novica 
            SET naslov = '$naslov', podnaslov = '$podnaslov', vsebina = '$vsebina', slug = '$slug', posodobljeno = '$posodobljeno'
            where id = '$idat'";

    if($conn->query($sql) === true)
    {
        echo "POSODOBO SI";
    }
    else
    {
        $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
```

Thank you in advance kind programmers.

LINK TO DATABASE STRUCTURE: http://ibin.co/1j1bFYAswzXI

Comment: does you query return > 0 rows? check with an else.. and set the value of $idat in else

Comment: Now that's interesting, it doesn't return any results! But how's that possible, I am catching and saving slug good I guess. But you know what happened to me! I've accidentaly updated all exsisting tables to the same $naslov when I didn't make a good update query! Maybe the problem is now that they all have the same slug! Can that be the this cases problem, that it doesn't know which id to pick?

Comment: @Ritesh I've tried to edit a news with custom slug, but it's still not working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `$idat` inside an if scope, to fix it, declare the variable outside the if statement, and try again.

```
$id = "SELECT id FROM novica
       where slug = '$slug'";

$result = $conn->query($id);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
    $idat = $row["id"];
    }
}
```

Would be... You have wrap a variable in a query with curly brackets. Please see the results now.

```
$id = "SELECT id FROM novica
       where slug = '{$slug}'";

$result = $conn->query($id);
$idat = 0;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
    $idat = $row["id"];
    }
}
```

Comment: It fixed the part of the problem, but still, the query isn't fetching any results and that is very confusing :/

Comment: Can you also post database structure?

Comment: Asap! As soon as kazam get's to it's sense

Comment: Here's the link to the database structure: http://ibin.co/1j1bFYAswzXI

Comment: It looks good, I really have to recreate the whole problem before I can find a fix.

Comment: If statement skips the part of if ($result->num_rows > 0) it has to be the source here :/

Comment: It seems I fixed the problem, please my updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I wasn't getting a right value for slug, I didn't define a good variable $slug in my other php file. Thank you all for your time.